# OpenSolaris Dead / Alive?

Tags: opensolaris

I have used Open Solaris in the past and really liked it, minus the lack of support for a few applications I use such as UFraw, Hugin, and wacom.  I can compile from source, but where is the fun in that.

It seems the release dates for the next Open Solaris keep getting pushed back and the release that was scheduled to happen quietly got pulled from their site.  So, they're no longer saying development for 10.03 has already begun because it has come and gone and there is no release.

Walter

Comment: Your question is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear answer (or no answer at all) from Oracle. Nobody knows anything and even the developers are coding in the dark. No one knows the future of openSolaris but in my opinion you should start to bury it.

Comment: (Open)Solaris will be released when ready, no sooner. "2010.03" is obviously not ready, that is IMHO not enough to bury it. Nobody knows anything: there are certainly people who know what is going on, they are just not sharing it. The developers are coding in the dark: What makes you think that ? Solaris developers are coding as usual (or more), currently working on build 140 http://static.opensolaris.org/on/flagdays/136-140.html (OpenSolaris 2010.H1 is build 134x (x being a respin like a, b, ...).

Comment: An insider guy told me about the coders, its not a fantasy of my mind. (And also an other person said the same about the fate of the whole project... thought it may be true.)

Comment: That's dubious. There is no OpenSolaris engineering so OpenSolaris is (mostly) developed by Solaris engineering. Solaris being Oracle strategic OS for the high end, what would mean "coding in the dark" ?
Also, build 134a (release candidate 1) has been released internally for testing. Doesn't looks like a canceled project to me. http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=128300&tstart=0

Comment: Didn't say cancelled, I say dying. :) Anyway, the fate is not known for the project. That's for sure. We'll wait and see.. :P

Comment: All projects die, eventually. Open Source ones are special as they can't be killed by their owners. IMHO, there is no sign this is happening with OpenSolaris which is active as usual having its source code updated regularly. 2010.03 is indeed late and people are complaining about it but they will certainly complain much more should it has been released with unfixed stopper bugs. I'm convinced it will be released when ready, neither sooner nor later...

Comment: I really liked Open Solaris as an OS for its reliability and just how well everything was integrated together.  Ubuntu has plenty of support and applications, but it it is still very fragmented and not integrated like Open Solaris is.  Maybe it is just me, but every time I do an OS upgrade, I get file system errors.

Comment: Maybe it would just need more time. I had only problems with the desktop performance and the multimedia support. Which were too.. uhm.. bad. :) Anyway, Oracle said. If something won't bring money, they will close that down. OpenSolaris won't bring any money. So it makes some sense. (Try Haiku, FreeBSD, something like that. Haiku looks promising and the things really got faster .. :P)